Is GJ 3470 a flare star variable type?
Is GJ 3470 (also known as Kaewkosin) a flare star variable type? I have wondered if it was a flare star variable type because it is an M-type star, and it could be possibly a young one.

https://arxiv.org/abs/2103.09864
